# Area 51 - alignment isssue in the progress proposal tab

Tags: bug, design, area-51, pagination

In Area 51 [progress proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress) tab currently 18 proposals are displayed.  In the end of the page there is an alignment issue.

The space between the proposal div and the disclaimer text is empty if I set the [pagesize is 30](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress&page=1&pagesize=30). It caused due to the pagination div is not displayed.

But if I set the [pagesize is 15](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress&page=1&pagesize=15), the pagination div is displayed and the spacing issue is not there. So even if the pagination div is not displayed, the spacing issue need to be fixed.

**Page size is 30:**
[image: Pagesize 30]

**Page size is 15:**
[image: Pagesize 15]